# Определить браузер PHP

Tags: javascript, php, браузер

Если я отправляю кому-то ссылку на свой сайт через телеграм (или иной месенджер), то нажав на ссылку во вьюпорте месенджера откроется **внутренний** браузер месенджера.

Задача на моем сайте определить, что открыт не **полноценный браузер**, а встроенный и попросить перейти в полноценный.

Могу использовать JS и PHP, само уведомление сделать не проблема, но помогите сформулировать условия для проверки

```
// Псевдокод
if(built-in-browser == true) {} else {}
```

Это не критически важная задача для моего сайта, однако если есть механизм реализации - буду рад рассмотеть варианты!

PS (на вопрос "а зачем?" ответ простой. Клиентам рассылку делает тг-бот, в сообщениях есть ссылка на сайт. Если клиент тапает по ссылке открывается встроенный браузер без куки, что заставляет пользователя чесать репу, вспоминать данные для входа и совершать прочие телодвижения, отвлекающие от покупок и тд)

Comment: для ios/safari можно проверить `navigator.standalone`.

Comment: Попробуйте [пакет с разными провайдерами](https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser), и посмотрите что будет детектить